# Oracle SqlError: Protocol Violation / OALL8 is in an inconsistant state

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, environment-variables, oracle-sqldeveloper, odac

I'm getting Protocol Violation and OALL8 is an inconsistant state exceptions trying to execute  SELECT queries, but only on SOME of my tables. I first noticed this in a test application that I wrote that did a `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE`. It would get through several hundred records and then just lock up on me. I tried running the same query in Oracle' SQLDeveloper, and would get the Protocol Violation exception on some tables. Eventually it gets to a point where it indicates "OALL8 is in an inconsistant state" for any query.

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix the problem? Where is my inconsistent state? Is Oracle's SqlDeveloper its own standalone client, or does it rely on ODAC or Instant Client (referenced in PATH envi var) to be present?

The only thing that changed recently was that I installed ODAC so that I could use odp.net to replace System.Data.OracleClient in .NET. IT was ODAC 11.2.0.3.0 with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, 32 bit. I since updated my PATH environmetn variable to point to my stand-alone instant client.

- Instant Client - 11.2.0.2.0, running on Win XP SP3, 32-bit Oracle DB:
- Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production, Running on Windows Server 2003, x64
- ODAC: 11.2.0.3.0

SqlDeveloper was installed before I installed ODAC, but somehow SqlDeveloper seems to be going through ODAC as the client, despite ODAC not being referenced in the PATH environment variable.

**Update:** When I initially installed ODAC, all of my queries functioned normally. Then they stopped functioning after a day, and I can't explain why. I attempted to uninstall ODAC, which failed when looking for a .DLL to delete. I then manually deleted my ORACLE_HOME, and reinstalled ODAC, and it's working fine for now. I don't understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer uses the ORACLE_HOME and it's drivers when available. The issue you are seeing in this is that the ORACLE_HOME is not the same version as the JDBC Driver bundled in SQL Developer.

The 'fix' for this is to ensure the oracle client is up to date w/ the version of sqldev you have installed. The easiest way to find this is when connection run `show jdbc`

```
show jdbc
-- Database Info --
Database Product Name: Oracle
Database Product Version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Database Major Version: 12
Database Minor Version: 1
-- Driver Info --
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 12.2.0.1.0
Driver Major Version: 12
Driver Minor Version: 2
```